# PHP register form strange error

Tags: forms, registration, php

i have a image hosting website, and my register form seems to be not working, every time i click on The second field it seams to go back instantly to the first field, Its really a pain in the b*m because whats the point if people cant register, does anyone know whats going on, i would really appreciate the help, Thanks.

Oh also my register form is located here - http://www.hostaimage.com/register.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shold try to wrap all the table in your html file with

```
  <form method="post" action="register.php" name="myForm">
```

just put it before the  tag.

also change the username field to something else

```
 <input type="text" maxlength=30 size=30 name="username"> // change name="username"
 <input type="text" maxlength=30 size=30 name="_username_">
```

there is already field calld "username" in this page - the field of your hosting website

Comment: I found your problem: change this label to div or anything else BUT a <label> tag:
<LABEL id="message" style="COLOR: maroon">

Comment: Thanks So Much Alon!! I Have Been Trying To Fix That For Ages, You Rock!!

Comment: That  really fixed it? Because there are so many things wrong with that page. It looks like most of the PHP needs to be rewritten, I'd shudder to think what quality it is.

Comment: Oh, Really? It Seams To Be Working Fine, And I Don't Really Think I Need Your Opinion, Did You Work On It, What You Said Is Quite Offensive, Did You Pay For It, NO! Keep Your Opinion To Your Self Mate.